# Sufficiency of $X_{(n)}$ for random sample of scale uniform variables.

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a random sample $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ where $X \sim \mathrm{unif}[0, \theta]$ for $\theta \in (0, \infty)$. Usually we prove that $T = X_{(n)}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ by appeal to Neyman's Factorization Thoerem.

I'd be interested in demonstrating the sufficiency of $T$ by showing that the conditional distribution $X\mid T$ does not depend on $\theta$. Is this something that can be computed easily?

Comment: Roughly, if you know the max is 21.2, then you know the others are no bigger that 21.2, regardless of what $\theta$ might be.

Comment: This idea is what led me to consider the problem, so from this perspective the result should be clear. But I haven't been successful in translating this intuition into some concrete, which is why I'm trying to explicitly compute the conditional distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional density function can be written as:
$$
\begin{split}
f(x_1,\ldots, x_n|X_{(n)}=m)
&= 
\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_1, \ldots, x_n|X_i = X_{(n)}, X_{(n)}=m)\Pr(X_i = X_{(n)}|X_{(n)}=m)
\end{split}
$$
By symmetry $$\Pr(X_i = X_{(n)}|X_{(n)}=m) = \frac{1}{n}.$$ Now consider
$$
\begin{split}
f(x_1, \ldots, x_n|X_i = X_{(n)}, X_{(n)}=m)
&=
f(x_1, \ldots, x_n|X_i = m, X_j \leq m\ \forall j\neq i)
\\
&=
\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n-1}\mathbb{I}_{\{x_i = m,\ x_j \leq m\ \forall j\neq i\}}
\end{split}
$$
Substituting these in the summation, we get
$$
\begin{split}
f(x_1,\ldots, x_n|X_{(n)}=m)
&= 
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n-1}\mathbb{I}_{\{x_i = m,\ x_j \leq m\ \forall j\neq i\}}
\\
&=
\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n-1}\mathbb{I}_{\{\max\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\} = m\}},
\end{split}
$$
which is independent of $\theta$.