# Density of conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density function $f(\cdot)$. Define $Y = 2X$, another continuous random variable. I would like to determine the conditional density of $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$. It is clear that $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = 0$ for all $y \neq 2x$ and for $y = 2x$, we should probably have an infinite spike. That is, $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ seems like a Dirac delta function, which is not really a function. Can someone suggest a proper way of handling this situation?

Comment: It's not a function onto the reals, but it's useful in some kinds of analysis.  Anyway, your assessment of the situation seems accurate.  Without knowing more about your application, I'm not sure there's a superior approach to the problem.

Comment: @BrianTung I was trying to answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233203/sufficiency-of-x-n-for-random-sample-of-scale-uniform-variables and ended up running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the proper density function for a constant is the dirac delta function. The CDF becomes the indicator function.

Answer (score 0):

$ f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\delta_{2x}(y) $.

That is, given that $ X=x $, $ Y=2x $ with probability 1.